# Postgres GENERATED AS IDENTITY conflicted with .NET Entity Model

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, dapper, sqlkata

I am building and API using .NET Core, PostgresSQL, and SQLKata+dapper (NOT EF)

I have this 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE "UserProfile"(
    "Id" INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    "Deleted" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    "CreatedBy" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "CreatedTime" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    "LastModifiedBy" VARCHAR(50),
    "LastModifiedTime" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    "FirstName" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "LastName" VARCHAR(50),
    "Email" VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "UserLogin"(
    "Id" INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    "Deleted" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    "CreatedBy" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "CreatedTime" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    "LastModifiedBy" VARCHAR(50),
    "LastModifiedTime" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    "Username" VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "Password" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "IsLocked" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    "IsActive" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    "UserProfileId" INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_UserLogin_UserProfile" FOREIGN KEY("UserProfileId") REFERENCES "UserProfile"("Id")
);
```

And in my C# I create entities to contain the table

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public bool Deleted { set; get; }
    public string CreatedBy { set; get; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { set; get; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { set; get; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedTime { set; get; }

    public BaseEntity()
    {
        this.Deleted = false;
        this.CreatedBy = "SYSTEM"; //TODO: Change to UserPrincipal
        this.CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.LastModifiedBy = null;
        this.LastModifiedTime = null;
    }
}

public class UserLogin : BaseEntity 
{
    public string Username { set; get; }
    public string Password { set; get; }
    public bool IsLocked { set; get; }
    public bool IsActive { set; get; }
    public int UserProfileId { set; get; }
}

public class UserProfile:BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    public string Email { set; get; }

}
```

Then here's come the problem, if I want to insert new record to database

```
public async Task<ResponseBase> SignUp(SignUpRequest request)
    {
        ResponseBase result = new ResponseBase();
        try
        {
            using var conn = await db.CreateConnectionAsync();
            var query = new QueryFactory(conn, new PostgresCompiler());
            var scope = conn.BeginTransaction();

            var userProfileId = await query.Query(UserProfileConst.TableName)
                                           .InsertAsync(new UserProfile
                                           {
                                               FirstName = request.FirstName,
                                               LastName = request.LastName,
                                               Email = request.Email
                                           });

            var affectedUserLogin = await query.Query(UserLoginConst.TableName)
                                               .InsertAsync(new UserLogin
                                               {
                                                   Username = request.Username,
                                                   Password = Argon2.Hash(request.Password),
                                                   IsActive = true,
                                                   IsLocked = false,
                                                   UserProfileId = userProfileId
                                               });
            
            if (userProfileId > 0 && affectedUserLogin > 0)
            {
                scope.Commit();
                result.Success("Success Insert New User");
            }
            else
            {
                scope.Rollback();
                result.Failed("Success Insert New User");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result.Failed(e.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The `new UserLogin({ })` and `new UserProfile({ })` will automatically set default value to `Id` from `BaseEntity` to `0`
And it will resulting error in `Postgres`

```
{
    "acknowledge": 0,
    "message": "428C9: cannot insert into column \"Id\"",
    "isSuccess": false
}
```

I know i can just create new `Object` without defining its class, but I wonder if there are any other way

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `KeyAttribute` annotation on the column to mark it as Primary key so it will be ignored on the Insert/Update queries.

Also you can use the `Ignore` attribute to ignore arbitrary fields

```cs
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int PrimaryKeyColumnWillBeIgnoredOnInsert { set; get; }
   
    [Ignore]
    public int ThisColumnWillBeIgnoredAlso { set; get; }
}
```

Check
https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/blob/master/QueryBuilder/ColumnAttribute.cs#L27

Comment: It works with `[Ignore]` but not `[Key]`
I think `[Key]` is just to determine which is the PK, but not ignored on insert
Thanks anyway